# Using AND and OR together in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm pretty new to coding/SQL, so this question is very basic.

I need to produce a report that contains 4 different vehicles makes under one dealership id. The following query returns only Buick makes:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
tbl_dms
WHERE
tbl_dms.id_dealer = '7039' AND
tbl_dms.make = 'buick' or 'chevrolet' or 'gmc' or 'cadillac'
```

Only thing I've been able to do to get my desired result is this:

```
WHERE
tbl_dms.id_dealer = 7039 AND
tbl_dms.make = 'buick' or
tbl_dms.id_dealer = 7039 AND
tbl_dms.make = 'chevrolet' or
tbl_dms.id_dealer = 7039 AND
tbl_dms.make = 'gmc' or
tbl_dms.id_dealer = 7039 and
tbl_dms.make = 'cadillac'
```

Is there a way to get this result without having to list the dealer ID every time?

Edit: If I use this:

```
WHERE
tbl_dms.id_dealer = 7039 AND
tbl_dms.make = 'buick' or
tbl_dms.make = 'chevrolet' or
tbl_dms.make = 'gmc' or
tbl_dms.make = 'cadillac'
```

Then it only links the dealerID with buick and searches our entire db for the other makes

Comment: Add brackets: WHERE
tbl_dms.id_dealer = '7039' AND
(tbl_dms.make = 'buick' or tbl_dms.make = 'chevrolet' or tbl_dms.make = 'gmc' or tbl_dms.make = 'cadillac')

Comment: ^^ No, that will not work. The `OR` in those will not select among the values inside the `()` but `tbl_dms.make IN('buick','chevrolet'....)` would.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Sure you are right, I fixed it. The approach with the IN operator would be still the more readable solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
WHERE
    tbl_dms.id_dealer = '7039'
    AND tbl_dms.make IN ('buick', 'chevrolet', 'gmc', 'cadillac')
```

You need parentheses if you really want the `OR` expressions

```
WHERE
    tbl_dms.id_dealer = 7039 
    AND (
        tbl_dms.make = 'buick' or
        tbl_dms.make = 'chevrolet' or
        tbl_dms.make = 'gmc' or
        tbl_dms.make = 'cadillac'
    )
```

It helps to explain why the parentheses are needed if I re-write the query to demonstrate how the server will actually look at each expression:

```
WHERE
    (tbl_dms.id_dealer = 7039 AND tbl_dms.make = 'buick')
   OR tbl_dms.make = 'chevrolet' 
   OR tbl_dms.make = 'gmc' 
   OR tbl_dms.make = 'cadillac'
```

Here, it's clearer any chevy, gmc, or cadillac would match, regardless of dealer, and that's what the original query was doing.

Finally, I notice those are all GM brands. The *best* thing would be a separate table for the `makes` which also includes a field for the `manufacturer`, such that these brands all share the same `GM` manufacturer value, and you can do a `JOIN` to this table to restrict your results to that manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use either of these two queries:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_dms 
WHERE tbl_dms.id_dealer = '7039' 
AND (tbl_dms.make = 'buick' or tbl_dms.make = 'chevrolet' or tbl_dms.make = 'gmc' or tbl_dms.make = 'cadillac')
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_dms
WHERE tbl_dms.id_dealer = '7039' 
AND tbl_dms.make IN ('buick', 'chevrolet', 'gmc', 'cadillac')
```

Answer (score -4):

Use parenthesis.

```
SELECT
*
FROM
tbl_dms
WHERE
tbl_dms.id_dealer = '7039' AND
(tbl_dms.make = 'buick' or 'chevrolet' or 'gmc' or 'cadillac')
```

Try this.  You'll get the dealership ID and any matches within in the parenthesis.

Comment: If you only add parenthesis, you still need to specify the column name before each value. ie (tbl_dms.make = 'buick' or tbl_dms.make = 'chevrolet' or tbl_dms.make = 'gmc' or tbl_dms.make = 'cadillac')